# Using multiple tables in Index View in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I know that If I want to see data from just one table in my Index View, I have to do this:

```
  public class LocalidadesController : Controller
{

    // GET: /Localidades/
    private Entities db = new Entities();

    //
    // GET: /Concessao/
    [Authorize(Roles = "ADMINISTRADOR")]
    public ActionResult Index()

    {
        return View(db.SINCO_LOCALIDADE_CONCESSAO.ToList());
    }
```

For two tables (in my case, views), I'm doing the changes below (localidades_view and municipios_view are the 
views that I want to select data). 
Model:

```
namespace SINCO_MVC.Models
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(SincoLocalidadeConcessaoMetaData))]
    public partial class SINCO_LOCALIDADE_CONCESSAO
    {

}

    public class SincoLocalidadeConcessaoMetaData
    {

        [Display(Name = "ID LOCALIDADE:")]
        public int[] IDLOCALIDADE { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "ID:")]
        public int IDCONCESSAO { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Localidade:")]
        public virtual LOCALIDADES_VIEW LOCALIDADES_VIEW { get; set; }

        public virtual MUNICIPIOS_VIEW MUNICIPIOS_VIEW { get; set; }
    }
}
```

View:

```
  <%@ Page Title="SINCO - Localidades" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<SINCO_MVC.Models.SINCO_LOCALIDADE_CONCESSAO>>" %>

 <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
     SINCO - Localidades
 </asp:Content>

 <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

 <h2>SINCO - Localidades</h2>

 <table>
      <tr>
          <th>
             <%: Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IDCONCESSAO) %>
         </th>
          <th>
             <%: Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IDLOCALIDADE) %>
          </th>
          <th></th>
     </tr>

 <% foreach (var item in Model) { %>
     <tr>
         <td>
             <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MUNICIPIOS_VIEW.NOME_MUNICIPIO) %>

         </td>
        <td>
         <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LOCALIDADES_VIEW.NOME_LOCALIDADE) %>

        </td>
```

I did something like this, but it didn't work, because this fields in index stays empty. 
How can I access the data of this views(oracle views)??

*Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Create ViewModel for your View which will consists from that two models.

Comment: Please show the code that didn't work. Showing data from 2 tables can mean anything.

Comment: I can't understand what you're trying to do here.  Your viewmodel uses SelectListItems, but your view has nothing to do with dropdowns or listboxes.  You're using buddy classes, but in a bizarre way that I can't quite figure out what you're trying to do.  Whatever you're TRYING to do here, it's so completely wrong that it's impossible to figure out what you're actually attempting to do.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch The SelectListItems I don't use in my Index View, but I'm using it in my Create View, so I excluded it from my question now, because I didn't asked about it. Sorry If I didn't it before. What I'm trying to do is only to see data from Localidades_view and Municipios_view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem it was because of LazyLoad. I added the tables in my model but because of LazyLoad nothing returned. I had to add this code below in my index:

```
   [Authorize(Roles = "ADMINISTRADOR")]
    public ActionResult Index(SINCO_LOCALIDADE_CONCESSAO model)

         {
                      return View("Index", db.SINCO_LOCALIDADE_CONCESSAO.Include(s => s.LOCALIDADES_VIEW).Include(s => s.MUNICIPIOS_VIEW));

 }
```

Now it's working fine!

Answer (score 2):

Make a ViewModel which contains two fields, one for each table, Done...something like

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public MyType Table1 {get;set;}
    public MyType2 Table2 {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: I am already doing it... The problem is that I can't select the data of this tables in my view.

Comment: @Jessica what happens when you try to select the data?

Comment: @mxmissile It doesn't return any data. I am knew in entity framework and mvc, so I don't know if I'm doing right. I just added the code `Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LOCALIDADES_VIEW.NOME_LOCALIDADE) %>` to my view, expecting that EF selects that data correctly. Maybe I have to do any LINQ query, but how?

Comment: @Jessica first, <% and runat server are for web form not MVC, second..you are iterating thru Model which you said contains two Tables, but you didn't specify which one. I would expect it to throw some exception complaining about IEnumerable not implemented exception....

Comment: @Steve the code `<% Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LOCALIDADES_VIEW.NOME_LOCALIDADE) %>` I added in my view, like I put in the question, not in my controller. The developer who started this project, didn't use razor, so I'm not using too. The tables that I am refering is two views (because I think that is the same mechanism of the tables) that I specified when I showed my model (localidades_view and municipios_view).

Comment: @Steve - you can use webforms view engine in MVC.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch not saying you can't..but you shouldn't.

Comment: @Steve - That's completely incorrect, Webforms is a fully supported view engine.  Certainly Razor is much nicer, and gives you more functionality, but there is no reason to say "you shouldn't".

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch why go with MVC if you want to use Webform. At least that's what I would ask if I see someone in my team does that.

Comment: @Steve - Webforms View Engine has little to do with Webforms applications.  You're still writing MVC regardless of what view engine you use.  There are a dozen other view engines out there you can use as well, such as nhaml, spark, etc..  the view engine is irrelevant to the difference between MVC and Webforms apps.